# How to show my plan after each part (\part)? (memoir class)

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, memoir

In the first page of my document a table of content is displayed. However, I would like to show a plan after each `\part` 's title. I don't have the slightest idea how to do it. Should I use `\tableofcontents` again ?

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Part ONE}
%HERE : show ONLY the plan iof the part ONE, that is to say chapter one + its section and Chapter two

\chapter{Chapter ONE of PART ONE}
\section{Section}
\chapter{Chapter TWO of PART ONE}

\part{Part TWO}

%HERE : show ONLY the plan iof the part TWO, that is to say chapter one + its section and Chapter two
\chapter{Chapter ONE of PART TWO}
\section{Section}
\chapter{Chapter TWO of PART TWO}
\end{document}
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "plan"? A new ToC? Then you should have a look on the package `minitoc` which does exactly what you want.

Comment: An additional `\tableofcontents` does it show again, but not a `toc per part`. Use, as LaRiFaRi already wrote, `minitoc`, for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `minitoc` package and the macros `\doparttoc` and `\partdoc` (in place where it should appear), this can be easily achieved:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{minitoc}%

\doparttoc% Prepare minitoc package for part tocs usage
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Part ONE}
\parttoc % Enable for the first part

\chapter{Chapter ONE of PART ONE}
\section{Section}
\chapter{Chapter TWO of PART ONE}

\part{Part TWO}
\parttoc % Enable for the second part etc.


\chapter{Chapter ONE of PART TWO}
\section{Section}
\chapter{Chapter TWO of PART TWO}
\end{document}
```

The screen shot shows the TOC of the first part only

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but it seems pretty hard to use.

Comment: @Terriguest: What is pretty hard? Writting two or three statements?

Comment: Writting 2 o 3 statements is not so hard. However, taking a look on the package doc makes me sick. I have plenty of changes to do because my divisions' documents (part, chapter, section &cp) are so customized. It sometimes hard to use Latex :P .

Comment: @Terriguest: The most of the 800 pages of the documentation are examples ;-)

Comment: Anyone would know how to get the effect of \parttoc without writing it when I write \part{something}

Comment: You could either use a command named `\mypart` which is a wrapper around `\part`, adding `\parttoc` or redefine the `\part` command.